# Flutter NodeJs Cloudinary Type int is not a subtype of type double

Tags: flutter, dart, try-catch

I am trying to display a list of Products which are stored in Mongodb, when I try to get them through a GET request, I get 'type int is not a subtype of type double' in the catch block.

I have created api for backend using nodejs, expressjs and hosting the data in Mongodb. While making the POST request, I used the Product class in both client side dart and server side mongoose model, but didn't encounter any error.

I also tried changing all double data type to int and tried accessing product lists, but then I got type double is not a subtype of type int error!

Here is the code:

the GET request

```
 Future<List<Product>> fetchAllProducts(BuildContext context) async {
    final userProvider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context, listen: false);
    List<Product> productList = [];
    try {
    
      http.Response res = await http.get(Uri.parse('$uri/admin/get-products'),
         
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            'x-auth-token': userProvider.user.token,
          });
      httpErrorHandle(
        response: res,
        context: context,
        onSuccess: () {
        
         

          for (int i = 0; i < jsonDecode(res.body).length; i++) {
           
            
            productList.add(
              Product.fromJson(
                jsonEncode(
                  jsonDecode(res.body)[i],
                ),
              ),
            );
            print(' error in above .add block');
          }
        },
      );
    } catch (e) {
      //error: type int is not a subtype of type double ..
     
      showSnackBar(context, e.toString());
    }

    return productList;
  }
```

Product Model Class

```
class Product {
  final String? id;
  final String name;
  final String description;
  final double price;
  final double quantity;
  final String category;
  final List<String> images;

  Product({
    required this.name,
    required this.description,
    required this.price,
    required this.quantity,
    required this.category,
    required this.images,
    this.id,
  });




  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'id': id,
      'name': name,
      'description': description,
      'price': price,
      'quantity': quantity,
      'category': category,
      'images': images,
    };
  }

  factory Product.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Product(
        id: map['_id'],
        name: map['name'] ?? '',
        description: map['description'] ?? '',
        price: map['price'] ?? 0.0,
        quantity: map['quantity'] ?? 0.0,
        category: map['category'] ?? '',
        images: List<String>.from(
          (map['images']),
        ));
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory Product.fromJson(String source) =>
      Product.fromMap(json.decode(source));
}
```

httpErrorHandle function:

```
void httpErrorHandle({
  required http.Response response,
  required BuildContext context,
  required VoidCallback onSuccess,
}) {
  switch (response.statusCode) {
    case 200:
      onSuccess();
      break;
    case 400:

      
      showSnackBar(context, jsonDecode(response.body)['msg']);

      break;

    case 500:

      
      showSnackBar(context, jsonDecode(response.body)['error']);
      break;
    default:
      
      showSnackBar(context, response.body);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a workaround. I also faced the same issue. In your 'Product Model Class' instead of using `final int` or `final double`, you can use `final num` as a datatype. Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that gets struck in a similar posn in the future:

In the product.dart file where the Product model is defined, I forget to add .toDouble in the factory constructor Product.fromMap:

before:

```
factory Product.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Product(
        id: map['_id'],
        name: map['name'] ?? '',
        description: map['description'] ?? '',
        price: map['price'],
        quantity: map['quantity'],
        category: map['category'] ?? '',
        images: List<String>.from(
          (map['images']),
        ));
  }
```

after:

```
  factory Product.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Product(
        id: map['_id'],
        name: map['name'] ?? '',
        description: map['description'] ?? '',
        price: map['price'].toDouble(),
        quantity: map['quantity'].toDouble(),
        category: map['category'] ?? '',
        images: List<String>.from(
          (map['images']),
        ));
  }
```